# Why does this constructor create a "delegate cycle"?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
struct ArrayND{
    ArrayND() : ArrayND(0) {}
    ArrayND(int n) : ArrayND({n}) { }
    ArrayND(std::vector<int> _shape){
      ...
    }
}
```

Compiler output (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)):

```
error: constructor for 'ArrayND' 
creates a delegation cycle [-Wdelegating-ctor-cycles]
      ArrayND(int n) : ArrayND({n}) { }
```

[This](https://thenewcpp.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/delegating-constructors/) article gives an example for a delegation cycle:

```
class C
{
  public:

  C(int) { }
  C() : C(42) { }
  C(char) : C(42.0) { }
  C(double) : C('a') { }
};
```

While I clearly understand the delegation cycle in `class C`, i don't understand it in `class ArrayND`.

**What's the reason for the delegation cycle in `ArrayND`?**

Comment: `{n}` isn't going to infer the type `std::vector`, so that's passing an integer back to the constructor.

Comment: `std::vector_list` was a stupid copy-paste error, as I was also experimenting with `std::initializer_list`. It's corrected now.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Why not? In the same program, I use the notation `f({1, 2})` for `f(std::vector<int> p)`.

Comment: That's because `{1,2}` doesn't exactly match a constructor without an implicit conversion. `{1}` does.